# Vertical and horizontal projection of curves in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Is there a way to compute vertical and horizontal projection of curves in OpenCV ? For example in this [paper](http://www.ee.iitm.ac.in/~raju/journals/j24.pdf) , they have computed vertical projection of written signatures. How would I do it in OpenCV python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a canny edge detector followed by a contour tracer:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html
After that you can use individual contours to calculate projection.